# Reset only 1 DIV using jscript or ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, reload

I am trying to reload a DIV without reloading the rest of the, I have found the bellow script on many sites incl this one but every variation I find of this is not working, if I include the # in the href it doe nothings, if I remove it it reloads the whole page

```
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
     $("#scratcher-box").load("index.php")
  })
})

<a href="#" id="refresh">click</a>
```

Tried disabling as many of the other mini scripts I have running, toggle div, delay load and a count. Have JQuery 1.7.2 loader as well as http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31213713/scratcher.js, with a few changes which broke the included reset button. My jscrips is lousy so looking for a backup plan in case we cannot fix up the reset, here is the original http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31213713/scratcher_orig.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>For one: you might want to return false in the function call, as you do not want the href to be executed. Returning false within the function will disable the default execution of the element you are wrapping the click on (executing the href in this case).</strike>

Second: you are trying to load index.php into an element with the id scratcher-box, which seems non-existent? You either forgot to create such an element or you did not post your complete code. Try the following:

```
<a href="#" id="refresh">click</a>
<div id="scratcher-box" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
      $("#scratcher-box").load("index.php")
      return false;
    })
  })
</script>
```

After review of the problem:
I've checked using your files on dropbox, the problem does not reside on the click event or within that event's call, the problem is within the changes in the scratcher.js file.

You've changed the number of 'Scratcher' objects within the javascript calls from 3 to 20. However, as soon as the scripts tries to get Scratcher4's width it throws an error on line 192 as there is no canvas element with ID Scratcher4.

This error is being thrown on loading the document, which leads to javascript being unable to do anything else besides waiting for you to fix that error and adding those canvas elements.

Besides adding the scratchers into the javascript objects, also create the canvas items within HTML. This fixes your error and this enables javascript to execute the .click call.

Comment: @Denis Jamin index.php is the page its sitting on, everything is contained in the 1 page. Here is the complete file as it stands now http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31213713/index.txt

Comment: I see you implemented the changes. Did this indeed fix your problem, are there any javascript errors that occur?

Comment: I've checked using your files on dropbox, the problem does not reside on the click event or within that event's call, the problem is within the changes in the scratcher.js file.

You've changed the number of 'Scratcher' objects within the javascript calls from 3 to 20. However, as soon as the scripts tries to get Scratcher4's width it throws an error on line 192 as there is no canvas element with ID Scratcher4. This error is being thrown on loading the document, which leads to javascript being unable to do anything else besides waiting for you to fix that error and adding those canvas elements

Comment: dude ur a legend. We had it at 20 as that was the clients original idea of quantity of scratchers. I had changed it down to 6 just after my last message to you as they had decided that last week but we are still busy with the design so the remaining 3 canvas's had not been entered. Commented out the last 3 entries in the js file and all is well now.

Answer (score 0):

probably you should prevent the default link action:

```
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     $("#scratcher-box").load("index.php")
  })
})
```

then make sure to have a `#scratcher-box` element in page

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code :
By adding preventDefault you can prevent the default action of anchor tag

```
$(function() {
  $("#refresh").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#scratcher-box").load("index.php");
  });
});
```

Comment: You might actually describe what you've changed and why in the future. This is only some copy pasta for RemeJ to use while it is more valuable to actually teach him why and how.

Comment: @Dennis Jamin at the time when I saw that question no one has answered, and after posting my answer i saw even u answered with samething.